# django: Cannot import jQuery library to extended templates

Tags: jquery, django

I have a **base.html** template which is inherited by some other template (i.e. **user_profile.html** page) like this: `{% extends "base.html" %}`

The problem is that jquery library is visible only for the **base.html** template. Code inside the `jQuery(document).ready(function())` which is placed inside the **user_profile.html** template does not run.

If I place a **second** import tag of the jQuery library inside the **user_profile.html** template its own jQuery in the ready() function runs ok but then the **base.html** cannot see its own jQuery ready() code (although there is the initial import tag there too).

This is what I use: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

(Hope that all the above makes sense.)

What am I doing wrong?

-EDIT-

this is base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- remote apis first -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

    <!-- then local -->
    <script src="/site_media/js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            alert('it works!'); //this alert popups normally
        });
    </script>

    {% block external %} {% endblock %}
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div id="wrap">

    <!--  same stuff for all templates is going on here -->

        <div id="content">
            <!-- main content area, different for each template-->
            <div class="main">
                 {% block maincontent %} {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- wrapper -->

    {etc...}
```

This is user_profile.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load my_tags %}
{% block title %}User Home{% endblock %}

<!-- following block is inside the <head> of the base.html -->
{% block external %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/css/maps.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            alert('hi!'); // it is never reached!
        });

    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block maincontent %}
    <!-- stuff is going on here -->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please post the code for base.html and user_profile.html to show how you are implementing them and how you are using the blocks.

Comment: Have you checked the html coming out of your server to make sure there's no errors? Jquery shouldn't care how your js is put together. have you tried debugging with firebug in firefox?

Comment: thanks, is there a web tool that will check my output code fore errors?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready
```

I assume there's more underneath the base.html ie block def for maincontent?  also, check out firebug, it's great for debugging js and other web stuff.

Answer (score 0):

solved:

It seems that if there is an error in the jQuery ready() function of the initial template (the one the it is extended by other templates) then the jQuery ready function() of all its children templates does not run.

This was the error
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=44999

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was an error further down (a call to a .js file wasn't found). This wasn't an issue in dev, but when it moved to production, it wouldn't work until I removed the bad call.